# Why is Webpack Adding a QueryString param after bundle url?

Tags: javascript, webpack

Where is this behavior coming from and why?

```
http://localhost:8080/client/scripts/app.24784a3c45a8fe3a7051.bundle.js?24784a3c45a8fe3a7051
```

I'm getting that happening to both my **bundle** and **main css** file.

I'm referring to this part, after webpack (v4) does its thing, why is it appending that `?24784a3c45a8fe3a7051`?

here is how I run it:

```
"prod": "NODE_ENV=production webpack --mode=production && yarn start",
"start": "node dist/server.js"
```

So from command-line: `yarn prod`

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link type="text/css" href="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/css/ink.min.css">
    <script src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/ink-all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/autoload.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html** (produced by webpack after the run):

```
<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>My Title</title><meta charset="utf-8"><link href="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/css/ink.min.css"><script src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/ink-all.min.js"></script><script src="https://ink.global.ssl.fastly.net/3.1.10/js/autoload.js"></script><link href="../client/lib/assets/css/main.5ea170bff2113561a355.css?5ea170bff2113561a355" rel="stylesheet"></head><body><div id="app"></div><script src="../client/scripts/app.5ea170bff2113561a355.bundle.js?5ea170bff2113561a355"></script></body></html>
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
const path = require('path');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

const isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

const html = () => {
  return new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: './src/client/index.html',
    filename: './client/index.html',
    hash: true,
  });
};

const copyAllOtherDistFiles = () => {
  return new CopyPlugin({
    patterns: [
      { from: 'src/client/assets', to: 'client/assets' },
      { from: 'src/server.js', to: './' },
      { from: 'src/api.js', to: './' },
      { from: 'package.json', to: './' },
      { from: 'ext', to: 'client/lib' },
      { from: 'feed.xml', to: 'client' },
      {
        from: 'src/shared',
        to: './shared',
        globOptions: {
          ignore: ['**/*supressed.json'],
        },
      },
    ],
  });
};

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/client/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'client/scripts/app.[hash].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devServer: {
    writeToDisk: true,
  },
  target: 'web',
  devtool: 'source-map',
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({}), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        styles: {
          name: 'styles',
          test: /\.css$/,
          chunks: 'all',
          enforce: true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'html-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [
          isProduction ? MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader : 'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader', options: { injectType: 'linkTag' } },
          'css-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: ['url-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: isProduction
    ? [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: isProduction
            ? 'client/lib/assets/css/main.[hash].css'
            : 'main.css',
        }),
        html(),
        copyAllOtherDistFiles(),
      ]
    : [new CleanWebpackPlugin(), html(), copyAllOtherDistFiles()],
};
```

Comment: Is this the dev server? It looks like it is just a repeat of the bundle hash.

Comment: no..it's production.  yea that's what I thought some kind of repeat, is this normal?  I updated the post with my webpack.config.js

Comment: How is localhost on a port that isn't 80 or 443 production?

Comment: doesn't matter, I'm testing this locally right now, so it's 8080

Comment: It seems that you are talking about this thing: `.[hash].` in your config. Please read about it in the [documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#template-strings).

Answer (score 0):

hash: true, will add Query params to you bundle